# WebSocket client can't connect to cloud server through corporate proxy except for web browsers! (ETIMEDOUT)

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, websocket, proxy

I'm trying to connect a WebSocket client (corporate Node.JS server) to a Cloud server, but it times out (connect ETIMEDOUT error).

I'm not sure which needs configuration... Linux, Node.JS or the WebSocket Client?

I've already configured the proxy for Linux (export proxy/https_proxy), and for Node.JS (npm config set proxy/https_proxy) but the problem persists!

I'm using the ws library found in https://npmjs.com and implemented it without any sort of options except setting port.

Any advice?

EDIT: Works fine in the web browser, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node does not automatically use any form of configuration for making HTTP requests through proxies -- ie, node does not read the `PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables.  `npm config set proxy` **only** affects npm itself.

In other words, node programs always try to access servers directly.  It appears your network requires HTTP requests to go through a proxy, and direct connections are being silently dropped.

If you  want your program to make HTTP requests through proxies, you must do so manually.  The [http-proxy-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-proxy-agent) module can help you do this.

Comment: Does Chrome's WebSocket implementation automatically use proxy? I will try out your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Chrome's WebSockets will use the same proxy server as regular HTTP requests.

Comment: Stupid question - but is WebSocket related to the HTTP protocol in any way?

Comment: Yes.  A WebSocket is initiated via a [HTTP Upgrade request](http://enterprisewebbook.com/ch8_websockets.html#HANDSHAKE).

Comment: Thanks, is it unsafe to assume that I can keep the WebSocket connection alive for days? Even with auto-reconnect?

Comment: That depends *entirely* on your network, proxy, and server configurations.  Really one way to find out: test and see how long the connection lasts.

Comment: _Really one way to find out: test and see how long the connection lasts._ Genius!

Also, the https-proxy-agent worked, thank you for everything!